# Pandas: How to determine if a column value is in another column's list

Tags: python, pandas

**Goal:** I have this dataframe where I want to see if a "Country" belongs to "Another Country's Neighbors" list:

```
Country     AnotherCountry  AnotherCountryNeighbors
A           X                [B, C]
A           Y                [A, B]
```

**Expected output:** If the country is a neighbor, I'd like to add a column "Country Neighbor", which is a boolean value:

```
Country     AnotherCountry  AnotherCountryNeighbors   CountryNeighbor
A           X                [B, C]                    False
A           Y                [A, B]                    True
```

**Attempt:** I tried using the dataframe.isin() function:

```
df.Country.isin(df.AnotherCountryNeighbors)
```

**Error:**

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `in` with `apply`

```
df.apply(lambda x :  x['Country'] in x['AnotherCountryNeighbors'],1)
Out[1425]: 
0    False
1     True
dtype: bool
```

Your AnotherCountryNeighbors is list , `isin` can not work with list *[values : iterable, Series, DataFrame or dictionary](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)*

Comment: @Alex added :-)

Comment: Thank you this did the trick! May I ask what the ",1" signifies in the lambda function?

Comment: @tjones You can check https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html, axis=0 means row axis=1 means column :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is one occasion where I find list comprehension + `zip` readable and efficient versus `pandas`:

```
df['CountryNeighbor'] = [i in j for i, j in zip(df.Country, df.AnotherCountryNeighbors)]
```